# How to convert Year(GETDATE()) to int in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, stored-procedures

I want to convert `YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE())` into `int`.

Here is my query

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE
DECLARE @EndDate DATE
DECLARE @EndOfMonth Date

SET @StartDate = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
SET @EndDate = GETDATE() - 1

INSERT INTO MyTable (StoreID, ItemID, Year, Month, Qty, ExtPrice, ExtCost)
    SELECT
        Storeid, ItemID,
        YEAR(Time) Years, MONTH(Time) Months,
        SUM(Qty), SUM(ExtendedPrice),
        SUM(ExtendedCost)
    FROM
        Records
    WHERE
        Time >= @StartDate AND Time <= @EndDate
    GROUP BY
        Storeid, ItemID, 
        YEAR(Time), MONTH(Time)
```

I get an error:

> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

When I create a stored procedure for above query, it throws the error mentioned.

Comment: What is the data type of the "Time" column?

Comment: YEAR() and MONTH() already returns type INT

Comment: @JasonA.Long `Time` datatype is `DateTime`

Comment: which data type you have for MyTable year and moth ?  could be that these columns are datetime

Comment: @scaisEdge `year and month` type is `int` datatype

Comment: Something is off with this scenario... If the data type information you've provided about the "Time", "Year", & "Month" columns is correct, there should be no problem (aside from how you're selecting dates) with this query. Can you post the actual error (in it's entirety) that you're getting.

Comment: @JasonA.Long please wait. I will update

Comment: As an extra step, see if you can run the whole query without an insert. Just to isolate if it's an error in the select or insert statement

Answer (score 0):

try using the following code

```
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: still same, No change

Comment: please show the table structure of MyTable and Records

Answer (score 0):

You should to cast ur year to int

```
CAST(Year(GETDATE()) AS int)
```